# How to add key pair value to an existing json file if there are quotes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jq

I have an existing key.json file that looks like this:
key.json

```
{
"resstart": 1700839261,
"resend": 1700839965,
"resop": "SUCCESS",
"resurl": "http://xxxx/",
"ressummary": {
  "value": 1,
  "expect": 0,
  "tool": "abc"
 },
}
```

I need to add the below section in my json under ressummary

```
"Check": [
   {
       "Check": "["A_DOG","A_CAT", "A_HORSE"]",
       "code": "C/C++"
   }
  ]
```

So the final json file should look like:

```
{
"resstart": 1700839261,
"resend": 1700839965,
"resop": "SUCCESS",
"resurl": "http://xxxx/",
"ressummary": {
   "value": 1,
   "expect": 0,
   "tool": "abc"
   "Check": [
     {
        "Check": "["A_DOG","A_CAT", "A_MOUSE", "A_HORSE"]",
        "code": "C/C++"
     }
   ]
 },
}
```

I am using shell script to generate the above json. My code is:

```
name="key"
ccheck=("A_DOG" "A_CAT" "A_MOUSE" "A_HORSE")
echo "{"Check": { "Check": "\['$ccheck[@]'\]", "code": "C/C++"}}" >> $name.json
sed -i "s/'/"/g" $name.json
cat $name.json
```

I am getting the below error:
parse error: jq 1 compile error

Can anyone tell me how I can get the desired json file ? I would like to do this with jq. Is there a better way to do this? I have tried define ccheck as a string and array, but i am not getting the  "" and , either.

Comment: Your `Check` line is not valid JSON.  What are you trying to do there?  Do you want it to be a list of 4 strings, or a string that happens to look like a list?  You can include double quotes in a quotes string by using a backslash:  `"my \"string\"."`

Comment: Why is there no comma after `"abc2"` in the desired outcome?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you import data using jq:

- use `--arg varname "value"` to have access to a jq variable `$varname` set to the string `value`
- use `--args "value1" "value2" …` (as last arguments) to set the builtin `$ARGS.positional` to the string array `["value1", "value2", …]`
- use `.ressummary.Check = […]` to set the `Check` field to an array as defined (or `.ressummary.Check += […]` to append to that array)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

ccheck=("A_DOG" "A_CAT" "A_MOUSE" "A_HORSE")
code="C/C++"
jq --arg code "$code" '.ressummary.Check = [{Check: $ARGS.positional, $code}]' \
   key.json --args "${ccheck[@]}"
```

```json
{
  "resstart": 1700839261,
  "resend": 1700839965,
  "resop": "SUCCESS",
  "resurl": "http://xxxx/",
  "ressummary": {
    "value": 1,
    "expect": 0,
    "tool": "abc",
    "Check": [
      {
        "Check": [
          "A_DOG",
          "A_CAT",
          "A_MOUSE",
          "A_HORSE"
        ],
        "code": "C/C++"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my shell command line with `jq`:

```bash
cat input.json insert.json | jq -s ".[0] * (.[0].ressummary * .[1] | {ressummary:.})"
```

```bash
cat input.json insert.json | jq -s ".[0].ressummary += .[1]|.[0]"
```

`input.json`:

```json
{
    "resstart": 1700839261,
    "resend": 1700839965,
    "resop": "SUCCESS",
    "resurl": "http://xxxx/",
    "ressummary": {
        "value": 1,
        "expect": 0,
        "tool": "abc"
    }
}
```

`insert.json`:

```json
{
    "Check": [
        {
            "Check": [
                "A_DOG",
                "A_CAT",
                "A_HORSE"
            ],
            "code": "C/C++"
        }
    ]
}
```

The result:

```json
{
  "resstart": 1700839261,
  "resend": 1700839965,
  "resop": "SUCCESS",
  "resurl": "http://xxxx/",
  "ressummary": {
    "value": 1,
    "expect": 0,
    "tool": "abc",
    "Check": [
      {
        "Check": [
          "A_DOG",
          "A_CAT",
          "A_HORSE"
        ],
        "code": "C/C++"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### Explanation

I am only explaining the first statement.
The correct `ressummary` we need:

```json
{
...
"ressummary": {
    "value": 1,
    "expect": 0,
    "tool": "abc",
    "Check": [
      {
        "Check": [
          "A_DOG",
          "A_CAT",
          "A_HORSE"
        ],
        "code": "C/C++"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So basically we just merge `insert.json` to the `ressummary`.

```
.[0].ressummary * .[1]
```

Using this statement will make a JSON file looking like this.

```json
{
  "value": 1,
  "expect": 0,
  "tool": "abc",
  "Check": [
    {
      "Check": [
        "A_DOG",
        "A_CAT",
        "A_HORSE"
      ],
      "code": "C/C++"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this should be place under the `ressummary`:

```
.[0].ressummary * .[1] | {ressummary:.}
```

Using this statement will get a JSON looking like this:

```json
{
  "ressummary": {
    "value": 1,
    "expect": 0,
    "tool": "abc",
    "Check": [
      {
        "Check": [
          "A_DOG",
          "A_CAT",
          "A_HORSE"
        ],
        "code": "C/C++"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then we can merge it to the original input.

```
.[0] * (.[0].ressummary * .[1] | {ressummary:.})
```

Use parentheses for priority arithmetic `.[0].ressummary * .[1] | {ressummary:.}`

PS: Using `-s` with `jq` will make it read multiple inputs as an array like this:

```json
[
  {
    "resstart": 1700839261,
    "resend": 1700839965,
    "resop": "SUCCESS",
    "resurl": "http://xxxx/",
    "ressummary": {
      "value": 1,
      "expect": 0,
      "tool": "abc"
    }
  },
  {
    "Check": [
      {
        "Check": [
          "A_DOG",
          "A_CAT",
          "A_HORSE"
        ],
        "code": "C/C++"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But I still recommend using Python to handle JSON.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the desired result in your JSON file using jq, you'll need to modify your approach slightly.

1. Read the existing JSON: First, use jq to read the existing JSON file.
2. Modify the JSON: Add the new "Check" section under "ressummary". Since you're dealing with an array of strings and you need to preserve the quotes inside the string, you'll need to handle this carefully.
3. Write the modified JSON back: Finally, output the modified JSON back to the file.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# The name of your JSON file
name="key.json"

# The array of items for the "Check" key
ccheck=("A_DOG" "A_CAT" "A_MOUSE" "A_HORSE")

# Convert array to a JSON array of strings
json_array=$(printf '%s\n' "${ccheck[@]}" | jq -R . | jq -s .)

# Use jq to add the new "Check" section under "ressummary"
jq --argjson arr "$json_array" \
   '.ressummary.Check = [{"Check": $arr | join(","), "code": "C/C++"}]' \
   "$name" > temp.json && mv temp.json "$name"

# Display the updated JSON
cat "$name"
```

- `printf '%s\n' "${ccheck[@]}" | jq -R . | jq -s .`: This part of the script converts the bash array `ccheck` into a JSON array. `jq -R` reads raw strings (one per line) and `jq -s` slurs them into an array.
- The `jq` command then adds this array under the "Check" key in "ressummary". We use `join(",")` to convert the array into a string representation, which includes the required quotes.
- The output is written to a temporary file (`temp.json`) and then renamed to your original file name. This is a safer way to modify files with `jq`.

Run this script in the directory where your `key.json` file is located. It will add the specified section to your JSON file as per your requirement.

Comment: When i assign a variable like this json_array=$(printf '%s\n' "${ccheck[@]}" | jq -R . | jq -s .) the shell gives  the following error: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
./t1.sh: line 13: `a=(printf '%s\n' "${ccheck[@]}" | jq -R . | jq -s .)'

Comment: `json_array=$(printf '%s\n' "${ccheck[@]}" | jq -R . | jq -s .)` is is syntactically correct for Bash and should not cause the error you described if `jq` is installed and available in your PATH.